# How can I execute different code (using nap) for different numbers of dimension in typescript arrays?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to alter a set of strings in a 1D or 2D typescript array as follows:

```
// this part of the code is from a library, I cannot modify it.

let x: string[] | string[][];

document.write(Math.random().toString());

if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    x = ["one", "two", "three"];
} else {
    x = [["one", "two", "three"], ["four", "five", "six"], ["seven", "eight", "nine"]];
}

// the code below needs to modify the output from the library

if (Array.isArray(x) && x.every(item => typeof item === "string")) {
    x = x.map(item => "prefix-" + item);
} else {
    x = x.map(item_array => item_array.map(item => "prefix-" + item));
}


document.write(x.toString());
```

I keep getting this error from the typescript compiler:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string[], index: number, array: string[][]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Is there some way that I can get the typescript compiler to realise the correct type in each of the braced sections?

EDIT: I have added the comments in the code above to point out that I cannot edit the code that does the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't understand then when you check `x` you are figuring out if it is a `string[]` or not.  The supported way to let the compiler know this is to package the check into a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), as follows:

```
// note that the return type of this is "x is string[]"
function isStringArray(x: any): x is string[] {
    return Array.isArray(x) && x.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}

if (isStringArray(x)) {
    x = x.map(item => "prefix-" + item); // okay
} else {
    x = x.map(item_array => item_array.map(item => "prefix-" + item)); // okay
}
```

That is more or less the same thing at runtime (with an extra function call), but now the compiler interprets `if isStringArray(x) {...x...} else {...x...}` as a check on the type of `x`.  In the "then" clause (where `isStringArray(x)` is `true`), `x` will be narrowed from `string[] | string[][]` to just `string[]`.  And in the "else" clause (where `isStringArray(x)` is `false`), `x` will *remove* `string[]` from the union `string[] | string[][]`, narrowing it to `string[][]`.  And then the code inside both those clauses compiles as intended.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. It is interesting that the compiler does seem to automatically correctly interpret the difference between simpler types, such as a condition using the Array.isArray() function seems to effectively (keep | remove) non-array types from a union in an "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation fails because when we declare a type of x as string[] or string[][]. when 
definition of x happens, type of x is assigned & fixed based on the value assigned to x.

To make Compilation successful =>

```
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    x = ["one", "two", "three"];
    x = x.map(item => "prefix-" + item);
} else {
    x = [["one", "two", "three"], ["four", "five", "six"], ["seven", "eight", "nine"]];
    x = x.map(item_array => item_array.map(item => "prefix-" + item));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have simplified the situation slightly, and I cannot actually modify the first "if" statement (it's part of a library). I'll update my question.